# Is it correct to use TrulyGamer or TrulyGamers combination of words?

Tags: verbs, adverbs, adverbial-phrases

So by definition Truly means something like genuinely, or properly, loyally or faithfully. So basically Truly Gamer would mean something like loyally or like real gamer.

But somehow I am not sure if it's proper use for this combination.

If I translate it to my language it translate it to something like real player.

So is it wrong or not to use this as a nickname or name for website or together genuinely like this?

Comment: Website has [trulygaming.com](http://www.trulygaming.com), and there is a YouTube channel called: "Truly Gamer 304". You can use "Truly Gamer" your as username/nickname, it does not need to be grammatical.

Comment: yes i saw trulygaming but i thought trulygaming is more correct than trulygamer or trulygamers. Like "This is truly gaming" but i see in comment below my nickname can also be used, as a shortcut to "We are truly gamers" but few people suggested me this is wrong. But for me it sounds pretty good and easy to remember.

Comment: You can use anything you want (within reason) for you "call-sign", so don't get hung up on grammar, use something memorable, it becomes your "brand".

Answer (score 2):

Well ... to be honest "Truly Gamer" sounds like it could be the name of a Bond girl -- but not the lead female.  Instead she would be the one who gets killed about a third of the way through the movie. Although I don't know if it's even really good enough for Bond. It could be the name of a girl in a Bond copycat movie.

But I digress.

"Truly" does mean "honestly", or "genuinely", but it's an *adverb* not an adjective, so it's normally used to modify verbs not nouns:

> He truly loves to play games.  He's a ***true*** gamer.

Use "true gamer" instead and you're good to go.

Comment: There are so many true gamer(s) out there with all the social and media accounts taken, now i realize why no one took TrulyGamer. My nickname is lonerunner, so would be ok to use lonerunnerGaming instead?

Comment: @AleksandarĐorđević You might be overthinking it a bit. TrulyGamer(s) isn't that bad a name. TrueGamer is obviously more popular because of the common adjective + noun composition, but TrulyGamer would be taken as: adverb(Truly) + adjective(Gamer, as in gamer mouse etc.) and TrulyGamers as a truncated version of "We are truly gamers" where, again correctly, the adverb modifies "are" and not "gamers".